# Javascript's redirection logic

Tags: javascript, redirect

So, if a have a Javascript function such as

```
function doSomething() {
     alert("Starting...");
     window.location = "http://www.example.com";
     alert("Completed.");
}
```

Why does the last line not work? I'm almost sure it's a security issue, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure it's just because you have left the page and the browser doesn't run javascript from pages not displayed.

To do this you'd probably need to use frames or else load the new page in an iFrame or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Since you redirect the page, your browser start loading the new URL (http://www.example.com). The current page is unloaded, and the execution of the script stops.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain it's like expecting lines of code in java or c after a `return` command to execute.  JS lives as long as the web page is open, and it dies as soon as you leave that page.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location = "..."` causes a new request to be made and a new page to be loaded, so nothing after it will execute.

Comment: So, it's impossible to do something after a redirection, right?